# stack overflow exception at program start (CUDA Monte Carlo Pi)

Tags: exception, cuda, stack-overflow, montecarlo, pi

My problem is that I am receiving a stack overflow exception at program start when the program first enters main. My program is a Parallel Monte Carlo Pi calculator using CUDA. When I try and debug the program in Visual Studio, the exception pops up before any breakpoint I can select. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

#define NUM_THREAD 512
#define NUM_BLOCK 65534

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function to sum an array
__global__ void reduce0(float *g_odata) {
extern __shared__ int sdata[];

// each thread loads one element from global to shared mem
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
sdata[tid] = g_odata[i];
__syncthreads();

// do reduction in shared mem
for (unsigned int s=1; s < blockDim.x; s *= 2) { // step = s x 2
    if (tid % (2*s) == 0) { // only threadIDs divisible by the step participate
        sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
    }
    __syncthreads();
}

// write result for this block to global mem
if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
__global__ void monteCarlo(float *g_odata, int  trials, curandState *states){
    extern __shared__ int sdata[];
//  unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int k, incircle;
    float x, y, z;
    incircle = 0;

    curand_init(1234, i, 0, &states[i]);

    for(k = 0; k < trials; k++){

    x = curand_uniform(&states[i]);
    y = curand_uniform(&states[i]);
    z = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    if (z <= 1) incircle++;
    else{}
    }
    __syncthreads();
    g_odata[i] = incircle;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main() {

    float* solution = (float*)calloc(100, sizeof(float));
    float *sumDev, sumHost[NUM_BLOCK*NUM_THREAD];
    int trials, total; 
    curandState *devStates;



    trials = 100;
    total = trials*NUM_THREAD*NUM_BLOCK;

    dim3 dimGrid(NUM_BLOCK,1,1); // Grid dimensions
    dim3 dimBlock(NUM_THREAD,1,1); // Block dimensions
    size_t size = NUM_BLOCK*NUM_THREAD*sizeof(float); //Array memory size
    cudaMalloc((void **) &sumDev, size); // Allocate array on device
    cudaMalloc((void **) &devStates, size*sizeof(curandState));
    // Do calculation on device by calling CUDA kernel
    monteCarlo <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, size>>> (sumDev, trials, devStates);
        // call reduction function to sum
    reduce0 <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, size>>> (sumDev);
    // Retrieve result from device and store it in host array
    cudaMemcpy(sumHost, sumDev, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    *solution = 4*(sumHost[0]/total);
    printf("%.*f\n", 1000, *solution);
    free (solution);
    //*solution = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume the problem is this:

```
float *sumDev, sumHost[NUM_BLOCK*NUM_THREAD];
```

for

```
#define NUM_THREAD 512
#define NUM_BLOCK 65534
```

That leaves you with a roughly 130Mb statically declared array. I doubt the compiler runtime library can deal with such a large static allocation, which is why you get an instant stack overflow. Replace it with a dynamic allocation and the stack overflow problem will go away. But then read [Pavan's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171447/stack-overflow-exception-at-program-start-cuda-monte-carlo-pi/6172096#6172096) carefully, because once you fix the stack overflow, the CUDA code itself also needs some redesign before it will work.

Comment: Ah yes that was causing the problem. Also Pavan's post helped me redesign my CUDA code.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the size of shared memory = size; like here

```
monteCarlo <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, size>>>
```

The value of size = 512 * 65534 * 4 = 2^9 * 2^16 * 2^2 = 2^27 (more than the maximum value of shared memory on any card I can think of).

But looking at your kernels, I think you want the shared memory to be equal to the number of threads you have.

So you either need to do

1)
this for launching your kernels

```
monteCarlo <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, (NUM_THREADS * sizeof(int))>>>
```

2)
Or use this for launching your kernels

```
monteCarlo <<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>
```

And this to declare your shared memory inside your kernel.

```
__shared__ int sdata[NUM_THREADS]; // Note: no extern before __shared__
```

I personally prefer method two for these kinds of kernels because the shared memory is proportional to the number of threads, but the number of threads is known to be constant. It is also slightly faster.

**EDIT**

Apart from the forementioned problems I doubt that this might be causing problems too.

```
 cudaMalloc((void **) &devStates, size*sizeof(curandState));
```

Becuase size itself is this.

```
size = NUM_BLOCKS * NUM_THREADS * sizeof(float);
```

May be you wanted to do this instead ?

```
cudaMalloc((void **) &devStates, (NUM_BLOCKS *NUM_THREADS)*sizeof(curandState));
```

As for the actual stack overflow problem you may want to look at [talonmies post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171447/stack-overflow-exception-at-program-start-cuda-monte-carlo-pi/6172420#6172420).

Comment: I doubt this is the source of the initial stack overflow

Comment: Yep you are right. Not too familiar with behind the scenes. I just pointed solutions for the obvious problems I found. thanks for clarifying stuff in your post.